# Can I use fstream for working with files with the Nokia Qt SDK?

Tags: qt, file-io, nokia

In my application (on [Nokia S60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) v3) I need to write and read some file from a device.
Can I use the standard C++ fstream? Or do I need a Symbian API class?

Where can I read some information about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fstream`s with Open C++ STLport library but since you're working on Qt, I'd suggest you use [QFile](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfile.html) instead.